# passport.js difficulty to get hashed password

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I'm using Passport.js in my application.

I'm using this salt:

```
7PJnpX5okg9ET2pZ2m5eyg==
```

And for this the hashed password is:

```
ZKRdKDloN37k9Bt070YMZkrqZw+e5IsFx/mdir3+QAEk1dDSp8+q1YJ57GvAQKU5dWIit55eNgWEcI4hd1N7vw==
```

Now when the user logs in, I'm using this code:

```
var userPass = 'testtest'
var salt = "7PJnpX5okg9ET2pZ2m5eyg==";
var hashedPassword1 = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(userPass, salt, 10000, 64).toString('base64');
```

`hashedPassword1` is different:

```
Gav+sH1tUG4xlBZOupBy+hcPMGbg5LexzONJuthJxnsY9/WvX17i2d9n6L292bXVsndHbcJfC2KeY3SL
```

IRBjEw==

Comment: I don't understand: `hashedPassword1` is exactly the same.

Comment: sorry sir hashedPassword1 is coming like this Gav+sH1tUG4xlBZOupBy+hcPMGbg5LexzONJuthJxnsY9/WvX17i2d9n6L292bXVsndHbcJfC2KeY3SL
IRBjEw==

Comment: And that's the same code that generated the password hash?

Comment: yes that is the same code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that your salt is a Base-64 encoded string, but you need its binary value:

```
var salt = new Buffer('7PJnpX5okg9ET2pZ2m5eyg==', 'base64');
```

When you use that, `hashedPassword1` will match the one you already have.